Unity TMPro InputField Decimal seperator
I have TMPro Input field and want to input decimal numbers only. On PC I need to press comma to seperate, point does not work. My phone does not support commas only points so I can only put integers.
The only code I used for that is the following:

I grabbed a reference with public TMP_InputField
I read the text with inputField.text

But that is not the problem. I don't change the text in the input field at any time. I just read it.
In the inspector I changed the content type from standard to decimal number.
I hae linked an image here, because I cannot post my own (I need more reputation).
I tried changing PC language before building, that did not work, I still needed to input commas. I tried replacing commas with points. That did not work either, Unity was removing the point before OnValueChanged event. Is there any way to change the seperation char or just set it to point by default?

well, it would depend a lot on how you're doing all that..  as I dont believe the input field has a mask setting, so it must be something you do by the code you didnt share.

Updated my question. What do you mean by mask setting? The only mask I know hides teft that is not in the area of a rect transform, but that's no problem here. I can't input the point symbol, regardless if it is visible or not

input masks are common for example in windows input fields you can setup like phone number formats etc.. I dont see why you cant put a comma in, because you have not shared what you are doing to stop other characters like letters and so on..

I have posted in my answer that I set the content type to Decimal Number. Doing that will mean I can only put decimal numbers (0-9, decimal seperator, - for negative numbers) . However, I can't put dots "." I can ONLY put commas ","        On my phone this will Lso remove every letter and symbol, so it is the right solution, but again, the decimal seperator is not workig

then it sounds like your regex is wrong. What was wrong with picking decimal above?

Ok, after a lot of research I found out about Unity's Culture Info Class. I called
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

To set default culture and UI culture to a culture that uses decimal point and not comma.

This is OK as long as you don't want to take the actual culture of your user into account and you prefer to force the decimal point as separator.

Can't you just check when the input field is edited if the typed text corresponds to decimal ?
public InputField inputField;
public List<string> supportedCharacters = new List<string>(){"1","2","3",".",","};//Fill here your characters

public void Start() //Call a function whenever the input field is edited
{
    mainInputField.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate {ValueChangeCheck(); });
}

//
public void ValueChangeCheck() //Called when the value changed
{
    foreach(string character in mainInputField.text){
          if(!supportedCharacters.Contains(character))
                 {//Do sthg to delete the uncorrect character}
    }
}

This would give you more control on what you can and can't type.

Yes I could but why do that when there is litterally an option to use only decimal numbers? Also, your answer doesn't change the keyboard to numbers only (I want to build for mobile), I think having all those letters there will only confuse people. I will try changing my CultureInfo in unity through a script when I'm home in a week and let u know if that worked.

oh okay you mean you want a special keyboard typing? I see but i'm sorry i don't know how to achieve this.

Ye if you set the pre-made content type keyboard also changes
